# Pass button action as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I want to generate buttons dynamically in my `html` template from an array of objects, like this:

**typescript**

```
private buttons: ButtonType[] = [];

ngOnInit(){

    let button: ButtonType = new ButtonType();

    button.name = "HOMEPAGE";
    button.clazz = "btn-blue";
    button.action = "goHome()";
    this.buttons.push(button);
  }

private goHome() {
    this.router.navigate(["/"]);
  }
```

**html**

```
<button *ngFor="let b of buttons" type="button" [class]="b.clazz" (click)="b.action">{{b.name}}</button>
```

Seems to work well except for the `action` part, that does nothing. It's not rendered at all the `(click)` part. Is there a binding way to make the `b.action` parameter interpreted as a method, as it would be if I write `(click)="goHome()"` inside the `html` page?

Comment: you can try with `button.action = goHome;` (no quotes, no brackets) and `(click)="b.action()"` (brackets). It should work but not sure because of typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to :

Change `button.action = "goHome()";` to `button.action = "goHome";`

And

`(click)="b.action"` to `(click)="this[b.action]()"`

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-function)**

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @esseara , Glad to know , Happy Coding btw ;)

Answer (score -1):

At this moment you're passing function **name** instead function/reference to it.

What you need to do is:

```
button.action = goHome()
```

You can also pass *annonymous function*:

```
button.action = function(){console.log('function called');}
```

By performing this action you will pass to your template a **reference** to the given function, which will be invoked after clicking on the button.

Answer (score -1):

Make these changes:

```
//Components
button.action = this.goHome

//View
(click)="b.action()"
```